# Variable cannot be resolved. Android regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to create a program that uses regular expression to scrape data from a website and then display it.

I've been trying for a while to figure out what's going on, but i can't.

> I am getting this error on those 3 lines:  m cannot be resolved

```
while (m.find()) {
String stateURL = m.group(1);
String stateName = m.group(2);
```

```
public class VisualizaActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visualiza);

    /* Imprime na tela
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(stateName + "," + stateURL);
    setContentView(tv);  */
    }



String expr = "<td><span\\s+class=\"flagicon\"[^>]*>";


public static CharSequence getURLContent(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    String enconding  = conn.getContentEncoding();
    if (enconding == null){
        enconding = "ISO-8859-1";
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), enconding));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16384);
    try{
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    } finally{
        br.close();
    }
    return sb;
}
public void x()
{
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(expr,Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(getURLContent(url));
    }
    finally
    {       
    }
    while (m.find()) {
        String stateURL = m.group(1);
        String stateName = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(stateName + "," + stateURL);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In addition to your scope problem already solved by Prince John Wesley you should not try to match html with regular expressions. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I think you'd have a much better time using something like XPath, though I'm not sure if there is an HTML Agility pack (or similar) for Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope of the `Matcher` instance is within the try block.

```
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico");
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(getURLContent(url));
        while (m.find()) {
           String stateURL = m.group(1);
           String stateName = m.group(2);
           System.out.println(stateName + "," + stateURL);
        }
    }
    ...
```